# Why does GCC (and Clang) not omit the frame pointer in AArch64?

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, arm64, abi

In [this Compiler Explorer example](https://godbolt.org/z/TMobjaKc8) you can see that for this piece of C code:

```
void unknown_function(void);

int non_leaf_function(int x)
{
    unknown_function();
    return x + 1;
}

int leaf_function(int x)
{
    return x + 1;
}
```

The GCC compiler generates this output (AArch64 target):

```
non_leaf_function:
    stp     x29, x30, [sp, -32]!
    mov     x29, sp
    str     x19, [sp, 16]
    mov     w19, w0
    bl      unknown_function
    add     w0, w19, 1
    ldr     x19, [sp, 16]
    ldp     x29, x30, [sp], 32
    ret
leaf_function:
    add     w0, w0, 1
    ret
```

It is clear that it doesn't have any problem with omitting the frame pointer (`x29` register) for the leaf function. However, for some reason, it feels like it needs it for the non-leaf function. Why can't it generate code such as this? (it seems that adding `-fomit-frame-pointer` does actually [generates this](https://godbolt.org/z/rx9b3994x))

```
non_leaf_function:
    stp     x19, x30, [sp, -16]!
    mov     w19, w0
    bl      unknown_function
    add     w0, w19, 1
    ldp     x19, x30, [sp], 16
    ret
```

Using `-O2` or `-Os` instead of `-O3` doesn't help. Clang also seems to have [the same behavior](https://godbolt.org/z/xhqjfx1xW), but not [MSVC](https://godbolt.org/z/dah4nTea6).

I thought that the ABI might forbid omitting the frame pointer for non-leaf functions, but [this](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/100067/0612/armclang-Command-line-Options/-fomit-frame-pointer---fno-omit-frame-pointer) says that it is the default in armclang.

Comment: The provided link says that "The default is -fomit-frame-pointer." but it also says "The -fomit-frame-pointer option instructs the compiler to not store stack frame pointers **if the function does not need it.**"

Comment: [This GCC ticket](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla//show_bug.cgi?id=100811) claims in comment 7 that the frame pointer is required by Linux's ABI. Though I couldn't immediately found a definite source for that claim

Comment: @SupportUkraine It omits the frame pointer on AArch32, x86 and x86-64 for the same function. Why would it be more efficient to include it on AArch64 (as I mentioned, MSVC doesn't)? A frame pointer should only needed if the ABI mandates it or if there's VLA/alloca stuff involved (or in ancient/obsolete architectures where you can't reference the stack using `sp` itself, such as x86-16).

Comment: [AAPCS](https://github.com/ARM-software/abi-aa/blob/main/aapcs64/aapcs64.rst#the-frame-pointer) requires a frame pointer for non-leaf functions, but then says that platforms can waive this requirement.  I couldn't immediately find info on the specific rules for Linux or other systems.

Comment: Since a non-leaf function must push x30 anyway, with `stp` you can also push x29 at no extra cost; it'll even be in the same cache line, thanks to the 16-byte stack alignment rule.  So the only real overhead of setting up a frame pointer, in itself, is the extremely cheap `mov x29, sp`.  As you note, you do have indirect overhead in a function which needs to save an odd number of call-preserved registers, since one of them could be pushed with x30 if x29 were not needed.

Comment: But compared to x86-64, the impact of maintaining a frame pointer is much less. And you're less likely to need it as an additional GP register in your code, since the machine has twice as many.